# How to select from VALUES in mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there some alternative in MYSQL for Postgres `VALUES` syntax:

```
select * 
from (values('1'), ('2')) as f;
```

Comment: I need join data from redis with table in MySQL. In postgresql i can do that with this syntax. I dont want create temp table in mysql and then join it.

Comment: In other words, you need a result set composed of literal values that your program retrieves from Redis.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL (as well as Postgres) allows you to `select` from nothing, so you can do this:

```
select * 
from (
  select 1 as some_value
  union all
  select 2
  -- etc.
) t
```

Since you intend to join this set to a table, you'll need to provide column aliases that you can reference later at least in the first inner `select`.